# MVC 4 JSON Route Post Data Routing without require parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing

In an MVC 4 route, I have a route such as follows,

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Comments_InsertComment",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{parameters}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Comments", action = "InsertComment", parameters = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

The method on the controller has a signature like this,

```
public ActionResult InsertComment(AddParameters parameters) {
    //parameters are passed in via jquery ajax post data
}
```

And I call them in ajax like this,

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Comments/InsertComment/null',
            data:params,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error - " + err);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Your comment was added!');
            }
        });
```

The problem I am running into is I have to specify /null or /anything in the url or it doesn't find it.  When I would like it to just be /Comments/InsertComment and then the post data.

I've gone through most of the similar routing questions I can find on here, but none of them are posting a json object to the controller from an ajax call (which works)...

I've tried setting {parameters} to {id} and setting id = UrlParameter.Optional.  I've tried leaving it off the route entirely.  I even tried paramters = UrlParameter.Optional.

And I am pretty sure it is not matching any other routes.

EDIT:

AddParameters is defined as:

```
public class AddCommentParameters
{
    public string ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public string BlockReplies { get; set; }
}
```

And params is set in javascript as,

```
var params = { ParentCommentId: null, CommentText: commentText, BlockReplies: null };
```

Comment: It needs to be `url: '/Comments/InsertComment',` (or better `url: '@Url.Action("InsertComment", "Comments")',` What is `params` (in `data:params`)? and what are the properties of typeof `AddParameters`? - they need to match up in order to bind

Comment: I updated my question with the requested details.  The reason I am not using @Url.Action... is because the javascript is a standalone file.  I have a register routes utility I call on any site using the comment system.  Also I am using '/Comments/InsertComment/null' because it does not work if I don't specify a parameter at the end, no matter what I specify, I just have to specify something.

Comment: I did find a default route handling it, so I changed it to be more specific and not handle the comments but the problem still persists.

Comment: Best way to handle the separate js file issue is to use a data attribute in the main views element that triggers the call e.g. `<button data-url="@Url.Action(..) ...>` and in the script, get it with `var url = $(this).data('url');`. As for needing to append `/null`, that should not be necessarily so there is something else at play if `url: '/Comments/InsertComment'` is not working.

Comment: Getting rid of the default route in my test app seems to have fixed it. /Comments/InsertComment is working now.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around why {controller}/{action} with controller set to Main and action set to {index} was firing for a controller called Comments and a method called InsertComment..

Comment: Possibly as a result of the order you defined the routes? (the order is important) The route above is a very general route and matches anything. To make it more specific it would need to be (say) `url: "Comments/InsertComment/{parameters}",`

Answer (score 3):

Please try using this code block in ajax

```
url: '@Url.Content("~/Comments/InsertComment")',
data: { parameters: params },
dataType: 'JSON'
```

I hope this will help.